# methods program not working of guessing a number

Tags: c#

I'm having issues creating a program that is a number guessing program. I think I have the written part right but possibly not the order of it? I have to use multiple methods such as a method for number generator of the number that is supposed to be guessed, a method for collecting the guess input, and method for checking the guess to see if it's right. I've literally have tried just about everything for days but all I get is rather a repeat of, "Enter the number: " even if its right, although it's supposed to repeat if it's too high or low. Or sometimes the console won't print anything. what is wrong? Here is the code:

using System;

namespace GuessTheNumber
{
    class Program
    {

```
    public static int RandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(1, 21);
    }

    public static int InputGetter()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter in a number: ");
         int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return guess;
    }






    public static String GuessChecker(int guess, int secretNumber)
    {
        if(guess > secretNumber)
        {
            return "Too high!";
        }
        else if (guess < secretNumber)
        {
            return "Too low!";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Correct";
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int secretNumber = 10;



        Console.WriteLine("" + secretNumber);

        while (true)
        {

            while (InputGetter() != secretNumber)
            {

                InputGetter();
                GuessChecker(InputGetter(), secretNumber);

            }

            if (GuessChecker(InputGetter(), secretNumber) == ("Correct!"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?");
                String input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (GuessChecker(InputGetter(), secretNumber) == ("Yes"))
                {
                    secretNumber = RandomNumberGenerator();
                }
                else if (GuessChecker(InputGetter(), secretNumber) == ("No"))
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Don't create a new `Random` instance each time you want to generate a new number, instead have a static instance.

Comment: @vc 74 it has to be random

Comment: @Techgeekgal19 The emphasis is on *new*; a new `Random` will start over generating numbers, i.e. start from the beginning.

Comment: @Techgeekgal19 My point is that recreating a random instance (with the same seed) each time is going to produce the same number: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vpW6XI

Comment: Stepping through your code with the debugger would probably be helpful in showing where things are going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You are invoking InputGetter() multiple times and your logic is incorrect.

It has nothing to do with Random instance being used.

I have quickly modified your code and it should work now as follows:
New number is generated, if you enter low/high message is displayed, if you enter correct number you are presented with the Would you like to try again message.

EDIT: I did not want to change original code much,In general Comparing strings is bad, you should not use it. Creating enum like and comparing would be much better

```
class Program
{
    public static int RandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        var generatedNumber = random.Next(1, 21);
        Console.WriteLine($"New Number generated! {generatedNumber}");
        return generatedNumber;
    }

    public static int InputGetter()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter in a number: ");
        int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return guess;
    }

    public static String GuessChecker(int guess, int secretNumber)
    {
        if (guess > secretNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too High");
            return "Too high!";
        }
        else if (guess < secretNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too low!");
            return "Too low!";
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct");
            return "Correct";
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int secretNumber = 10;

        Console.WriteLine("" + secretNumber);

        while (true)
        {
            int enteredNumber = 0;

            do
            {
                enteredNumber = InputGetter();
            } while (GuessChecker(enteredNumber, secretNumber)!="Correct");

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?[Yes/No]");
            String input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input=="Yes")
            {
                secretNumber = RandomNumberGenerator();
            }
            else 
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The `CompareTo` method was designed primarily for use in sorting or alphabetizing operations. It should not be used when the primary purpose of the method call is to determine whether two strings are equivalent. To determine whether two strings are equivalent, call the `Equals` method."* - [CompareTo docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto)

Comment: It should not use Strings for comparison as well but rather enums or int. I didnt want to change his code too much thats why i just fixed it and left most of the original code as it was ...

Comment: Don't make bad code worse with more bad code. The original used string comparison with `==` which is better than `CompareTo`

Comment: @vc74 I need the program to not ask if I want to play again if I get the number wrong and instead let me keep guessing until I get the number right and then it can ask if I want to play again and generate a new number